# Javascript client side auth customizing Backbone.Sync, does this make sense?

Tags: javascript, authentication, backbone.js, marionette

I'm new to Backbone / Marionette and I am having some trouble implementing authorization on my client app. Basically I have a app that have some public and private routes and I need to automate the login flow when the user tries to do some private action, like the original private user flow halts, start the login flow and then resumes the original user flow. Pretty standard stuff...

I am trying to find a way to automate or intercept and implement this behavior from my client app. I am not using any server redirect since that strategy reloads my app all over again and destroys my state, so I am trying to add some custom code to `Backbone.sync` to accomplish this.

In essence what I am doing is extending `Backbone.Model` to use my custom `sync`, that custom `sync` should return a custom promise (not the `$.ajax`) like the original `Backbone.sync`, I always try to resolve the promise using the original sync but if I catch an 401 from server I add Sync context (method, model, options) and also my custom promise object to my globally accessible App object, then i navigate my app to login, "halting" the user flow. Once user submit login info I check if there is a Deferred object on App, if so I call `Backbone.sync` with the original context and resolve the initial custom promise with that result ("resuming user flow"), then I just finish navigating to the original fragment to sync URLs.

I find this a simple solution in idea but does it make sense in Backbone / Marionette context app?

Here's my customSync

```
function (method, model, options) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  if (options)
    deferred.then(options.success, options.error);

  var sync = Backbone.sync(method, model, _.omit(options, 'success', 'error'));

  sync.done(deferred.resolve);
  sync.fail(function() {
    if (sync.status === 401) {
      // Add logic to send the user to the login page,
      // or general authentication page.
      App.Defer = deferred;
      App.Callback = Backbone.sync;
      App.Arguments = [method, model, _.omit(options, 'success', 'error')];
      App.Fragment = Backbone.history.fragment;
      // In this example, we'll send the user to the "login" page:
      App.navigate("login", { trigger: true, replace: true });
    } else {
      deferred.reject.apply(sync, arguments);
    }
  });

  return deferred;
}
```

And my login submit event of LoginView

```
loginView.on('auth:login', function (data) {
  var sessionModel = new App.Models.Session();
  sessionModel.login(data, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return loginView.setError(err);
    App.trigger('set:user', user);

    var defer = App.Defer;
    var callback = App.Callback;
    var arguments = App.Arguments;
    var fragment = App.Fragment;

    delete App.Defer;
    delete App.Callback;
    delete App.Arguments;
    delete App.Fragment;

    if (defer) {
      callback.apply(this, arguments).then(defer.resolve, defer.reject);
      App.navigate(fragment, { trigger: false, replace: true });
    } else {
      App.navigate('', { trigger: true, replace: true });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting idea but I'm not sure it does you much good in practice.  After login you are going to redirect the user back to the route they were on when the 401 occurred.  That route processing is going to end up re-making the service request anyways (unless you do a lot of work to avoid that) so resolving the previously rejected promise won't do any good.  I also wouldn't expect promise libraries to all behave the way you want when a rejected promise is later resolved.  From a coding perspective, if you do this try to avoid global state - you can pass the data back in the .reject arguments and keep global state clean (which will be particularly important when you have views calling multiple services asynchronously).  One more thing... from a security perspective, it would be crucial to ensure that you are dealing with the same user account before and after the 401.

I have done something very similar to this when working with OAuth services where a custom sync method looks for 401s and then attempts to use the refresh_token to get a new access_token then retry the initial request - but retrying a request after kicking the user to a login screen seems a step too far.

Comment: Hi Robert,

thank you for your answer,  but the initial request promise doesn't get fulfilled or reject on 401, it simply stays there halting user flow. On 401 the promise it is saved on App global scope and only after login finishes, i try to complete the promise retrying Backbone.Sync with the original context.

Also if you check the trigger value on navigate on finishing login is set to false so the original route is not triggered again.

Answer (score 0):

The `Backbone.sync` function seems like a strange place to be handling navigation logic. Sync is for managing your model states, and not the UI. It also seems doubtful that you want to universally retry every sync that fails. What seems more likely to me is that you may want to preserve data that might otherwise be lost by redirects (e.g form data). This is easy with Backbone because you can continue to pass references to models around.

I'd recommend that you get rid of all the global variables and routing logic in your `Backbone.sync` override. Instead just trigger an event and pass any information you may want to have to a separate handler. Something like this:

```
sync.fail(function() {
  if (sync.status === 401) {
    App.vent.trigger("sync:failed", method, model, options);
  }
});
```

This gives you a lot more flexibility with how to handle failures, keeps your sync function clear of navigation code, and makes it much easier to handle the nasty cases you are going to run into with globals (especially since you are likely to get a set of sync calls failing together, not just one).

Now add some handlers to listen for failures.

```
var redirectTo = "";
App.vent.on("sync:failed", function () {
  // Handle routing
  redirectTo = Backbone.history.fragment; // Use this url when navigating after auth
  Backbone.history.navigate("login", true);
});

App.vent.on("sync:failed", function (method, model, options) {
  // Handle model data you care about
  // e.g. manage a queue of unsaved changes; clear changes that didn't save; preserve UI specific models, etc.
});
```

If you are dead set on retrying your promises, you should do it this way as well, especially because you are going to want to only retry selectively (not to mention the issues brought up by Robert around this).

Below is how I would setup a handler to resubmit a message after logging in:

```
App.vent.on("sync:failed", function (method, model, options) {
  if (model.retrySaveOnLogin) { // Property I would include on models that can be safely retried
    model.listenOnce(App.vent, "login:success", function () { // Some event you trigger when login is successful
      this.save({}, options);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, i understand that using this approach and asynchronously use multiple models could call Sync and receive a 401 i would need something like pushing the Sync promise in a queue and once login finish resolve all pending Syncs. But imagine this scenario, i enter my app (without log in) and search for a user, i open is profile and have a message box ready to send him a message, i write my message and click send. How can i catch that send message that will require login, ask user for log in and once logged in finishes send the message with no need of user write it all over again?

Comment: Rui, I would use a method like I purposed for that situation. Specifically, the module that handles the route you are returning to should also have caught the failure event and kept the model object that backs the message box. Then when you return to that route, the controller will retrieve that model and populate the message box in the view. Let me know if that is not a helpful explanation or if you have issues with this approach.

Comment: Hi Andrew, but that way you simply return to the same state before 401 but logged in, the user need to click again the send button to really send the message... no? In my example the user don't need to click send again because the original model.save is resumed right where it detected the 401.

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. If you want to submit the message after logging in without any user interaction, I added a code example of how you might do that into my answer.

Comment: OK, but what about save callbacks, for example, once finish save re-render parent view, or even navigate to other fragment... since you are doing the model.save elsewhere you loose all UI context and are unable to do that kind of stuff.

Comment: You can pass through the `options` that include the success/failure handlers and other options (though I probably wouldn't). Beyond that, you can still have listeners on the `"sync"` event for the model. Most of your UI context will have probably been blown by redirecting though. So it is likely that you no longer want all of those handlers going off. Using the `"sync"` event instead of the success handler is your best bet and this saves you from needing to worry about cleaning up zombies.

Comment: I understand that coding this way makes me change my controllers in a way that some of its code gets executed and some of if gets halted waiting for models. The problem is that now, the is another controller that change the App Regions and UI, for example: LoginView making my models callback pretty "useless" because the UI ins't on that state anymore... (i think this is what Robert Levy referred to "(unless you do a lot of work to avoid that)". But even so still don't an alternative way to get the exact same behavior i am getting right now...

Comment: Yeah, the problems you mention are pretty much why you shouldn't be doing this kind of stuff. It's kind of like asking what kind of bullets you should use to shoot yourself in the foot.